# Mail bounces when I am sending from another domain to our domain in Exchange 2007

Tags: exchange-2007

when i am sending the mail another domain into our domain inno.net teh message is some:

Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:

```
 dev@inno.net
```

Technical details of permanent failure:

```
Google tried to deliver your message, but it was rejected by the server for the recipient domain inno.net by mx2.indom.com. [212.53.64.82].
```

The error that the other server returned was:
`550 We don't handle mail for inno.net`

----- Original message -----

```
X-Google-DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
        d=1e100.net; s=20130820;
        h=x-gm-message-state:mime-version:in-reply-to:references:date
         :message-id:subject:from:to:content-type;
        bh=PeByD/AlFHbkeWE1PlKVROrTsOy9y9Er6qEYvcSyI/w=;
        b=Hh1Dz5yTV4vENS5Lbp3+PP7q6H7ZZFh4hiAcf5UnzhidL0DL1ZLuNJcZq8WKT2DNTo
         GqVl84erPvB+FuldyZS927eK12KePBy9UE9pT7BqPMgJxPlh1qVXxvTZ7x3Tq9IeB2p3
         O6p6QWqQsfddMJGYGwkpgUJyyWruAS9ELdITLexnPmJgsBVGgw3yzyM20hNVYv3WQwpw
         xxAHIsPF2Ie1k6VpB/mc4MLtjyz729Y2AIk+0SbLvJulAVvkSkizWENy3LVi/frGBIMt
         CGsyGCgrUx1zR5j041iG+uM5nSme+j7sg436rI4ywkxQFhIH5T1Hr0SA8RVaORZEr+3U
         8+PA==
X-Gm-Message-State: ALoCoQmEb6J7MvbvpuEFmkPgsA5iSKAs+o+Xl+fgD/p2qPlmTeutnPJoDZEaS73hZ/4LBR5btykU
MIME-Version: 1.0
X-Received: by 10.180.37.199 with SMTP id a7mr962177wik.43.1377797756466; Thu,
 29 Aug 2013 10:35:56 -0700 (PDT)
Received: by 10.180.206.230 with HTTP; Thu, 29 Aug 2013 10:35:56 -0700 (PDT)
X-Originating-IP: [61.16.236.197]
In-Reply-To: <CALb+qFJ9ZBC_wd9SJCV-hzwBE1qCwCY2VuKFUB3=KbsA7gN3Xw@mail.gmail.com>
References: <4F2BF58583A0C74FB3395EFE36FB614E019FAE7644@Domain.inno.net>
        <CALb+qFJ9ZBC_wd9SJCV-hzwBE1qCwCY2VuKFUB3=KbsA7gN3Xw@mail.gmail.com>
Date: Thu, 29 Aug 2013 23:05:56 +0530
Message-ID: <CALb+qFJHvNAbo829CcqoiPEmZW8BtVXG0+KbRMGnhOisu5y=fA@mail.gmail.com>
```

Comment: The problem seems pretty clear to me: "550 We don't handle mail for inno.net". Have you set up inno.net as an Accepted Domain in Exchange and have you created a mailbox and email address for dev@inno.net? If not, you need to.

Comment: to add to what joequerty said, is 212.53.64.82 the right IP for your server?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the mx records for inno.net, they seem to point to the registrar you bought the domain from, indom.com

You'll need to update your MX records for inno.net to point to your Exchange server and not the , assuming you setup everything in Exchange/firewalls/etc. up front correctly first.

Like Fiddler said...it doesn't look like you are pointing `inno.net` to your own Exchange server but rather to a domain registrar named `indom.com`.